# Hibernate: mapping many-to-one association to different parent table depending on type?

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I have tables which look like this:

Item table:

```
ItemName   Varchar2(200)
ItemId     Number
OwnerId    Number
OwnerType  number
```

Person table:

```
PersonName Varchar2(200)
PersonId   Number
```

Company table:

```
CompanyName Varchar2(200)
CompanyId   Number
```

When the ownerType for an Item is '1', the ownerId of the item is a foreign key PersonId of the 'person' table.  When the OwnerType is '2', the ownerId is a foreign key of the CompanyId of the Company table.

I didn't do the data modelling & I don't have the option of changing the schema.

I'd like to solve two problems: 
(1) I'd like a mapping file for the Item table which would give me the items's owner.
(2) I'd like mapping files for the Person & Company tables which would give me the Items owned by the Person or Company, respectively.

Note: a CompanyId and a PersonId can be the same number, so an item is only owned by a Person when person.personid = item.ownerid and item.ownertype = 1.

I can control the mapping files & the object diagram, so I could create an Owner interface or super-class.

Can Hibernate do this sort of thing?

Answer (score 0):

- `Case 1`:  you can use the concept of `Table per class hierarchy`.
- `Case 2`:  map items as set for person/company class with where
  condition on the set mapping.